# Why doesnt make create file for the target " other_file" in below example?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am new to make utility and I was going through a tutorial. In the tutorial, they gave an example where every time we run make on it, the targets are executed because target file is not created.
My question is why isn't target file created in this example?
As per my understanding, when the commands are executed, the target file gets created. Next time when make runs on the file, it checks whether target file is present or not. If present, then it doesn't execute the commands again.

I am using GNU make 4.3 on debian.

```
some_file: other_file
    echo "This will always run, and runs second"
    touch some_file

other_file:
    echo "This will always run, and runs first"
```

the above always executed in that order because some_file depends on other_file which is never created. Why isn't other_file file created?

Comment: It's your responsibility to write recipes so that they actually create the files they promise to.

Comment: Seems to work for me.  Is this the actual file you're testing with?

Comment: Is "other_file" created for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As per my understanding, when the commands are executed, the target file gets created.

Not necessarily.  When the commands for a target are executed, the result is whatever effect those commands have.  Often it is desired that they should create a file with the same name as the target, but that's not automatic.  If that's what the makefile author intends then it is the author's responsibility to provide a recipe that achieves it.

In this regard, note a key difference between your recipe for `some_file` and your recipe for `other_file`: the former contains the command `touch some_file`, which will create that file if necessary and set its last modification timestamp in any case.  The latter contains no such command.

So,

> Why isn't other_file file created?

Because the recipe for `other_file` does not have that effect.

Comment: got it. Thank you. Also, what does the target file even contain? I tried to open one with gedit but it was empty. Is it considered good practice to create target files?

Comment: @Jane, the target file contains whatever the recipe puts in it, if anything, or whatever was already in it if the recipe is not run.  This is a question of how one chooses to *use* `make`.  It is not dictated by or even relevant to `make` itself.

Comment: @jane, you seem to be coming at `make` from the wrong direction.  Its primary intent and purpose is to manage software builds.  In such a context, targets often represent actual files that may need to be built -- object files, libraries, executables, *etc*.  The recipe for such a target must indeed create the intended file, else it does not serve its purpose.  Although `make` can be used for other purposes, too, you will probably find it easier to learn `make` from the perspective of how to use it to build software, as opposed to learning it in the abstract, without context.

Comment: You are right. I was just confused because of the couple of examples shared in tutorial. Its intention may not be wrong, but it's not the best tutorial, I guess.